# Pycharm:not through or through

Tags: python, pytest

Input:

```
def myPlus(myA,myB):
    return myA+myB
def myMinus(myA,myB):
    return myA-myB
print("#",myPlus(1,2))
# 3
```

in the middle1:

print statement add

```
def myPlus(myA,myB):
    print("# Line1")  
    return myA+myB
    print("# Line2")
def myMinus(myA,myB):
    print("#Line3")   
    return myA-myB
    print("# Line4")
print("#",myPlus(1,2))
print("# Line5")
# Line1
# 3
# Line5
```

Line1,Line5       :     pass through

Line2,Line3,Line4 : not pass through

in the middle2:

print statement <#> add

```
def myPlus(myA,myB):
    print("# Line1")     #---> print("# Line1","# Line2")
    return myA+myB
    # print("# Line2")
def myMinus(myA,myB):
    print("#Line3")       #---> print("# Line3","# Line4")
    return myA-myB
    # print("# Line4")
print("#",myPlus(1,2))
print("# Line5")
# Line1                    #---> print("# Line1","# Line2")       
# 3
# Line5
```

Line3,Line4 not found

Output:

comment mark add

```
def myPlus(myA,myB):
    return myA+myB
#def myMinus(myA,myB):
#    return myA-myB
print("#",myPlus(1,2))
```

pytest Possible?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I dont quite understand your question... but there isnt much point in having that print after the return as it will never get hit

Comment: everything behind `return` gets ignored and you never run `myMinus`

Answer (score 0):

Anything after `return` will be ignored. Just like behind a `While 1:` or a `While True:` That why these lines are not reachable. replace `return`'s with `print(whatyouwanttoprint)`